# Custom binding for $.expandingTextarea with knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am writing a custom binding to use [$.expandingTextarea](https://github.com/bgrins/ExpandingTextareas) with [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Following the excellent article [Another Look at Custom Bindings for KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html), I hoped it would be as simple as:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.expandingTextarea = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    $(element).expandingTextarea();
  },
   update: function(element, valueAccessor, aBA, vm) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, aBA, vm);
    $(element).expandingTextarea("resize");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work as expected - i.e. when changes are made to the textarea, the corresponding view model is not updated. Here's a [jsFiddle that illustrates](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/pxZmH/) the problem.

How does one create a KO custom binding for the expandingTextarea plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [the solution on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmh_ca/pxZmH/1/), namely also adding the value binding's `init` (which has the code to capture the events specified by the `valueUpdate` parameter):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.expandingTextarea = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, aBA, vm) {
        $(element).expandingTextarea();
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, aBA, vm);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, aBA, vm) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, aBA, vm);
        $(element).expandingTextarea("resize");
    }
};
```

I hope this helps someone else! :)